# Invalid argument error tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a model that takes two images (one taken right after the other) and train it so that it can predict how much the camera has moved between the two images. I use a smaller model that processes one image at a time, then concatenate the two outputs in a larger model.

I tried testing it and the model compiles just fine, but it crashes when I call fit() and gives me an invalid argument error.

```
Epoch 1/5
2021-10-11 11:41:23.993854: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-10-11 11:41:28.606390: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:369] Loaded cuDNN version 8200
      7/Unknown - 18s 81ms/step - loss: 63.80682021-10-11 11:41:41.279014: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1692] OP_REQUIRES failed at transpose_op.cc:143 : Invalid argument: transpose expects a vector of size 3. But input(1) is a vector of size 4
2021-10-11 11:41:41.279317: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1692] OP_REQUIRES failed at transpose_op.cc:143 : Invalid argument: transpose expects a vector of size 3. But input(1) is a vector of size 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/.../Deep Sight/deep_sight.py", line 155, in <module>
    main()
  File "d:/.../Deep Sight/deep_sight.py", line 150, in main
    final_model.fit(train_data, epochs=5)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1184, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 885, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 917, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3040, in __call__
    filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1964, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 596, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  transpose expects a vector of size 3. But input(1) is a vector of size 4
         [[{{node gradient_tape/model_1/model/conv2d/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropFilter-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer}}]]
         [[Func/mean_squared_error/cond/then/_0/input/_29/_48]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  transpose expects a vector of size 3. But input(1) is a vector of size 4
         [[{{node gradient_tape/model_1/model/conv2d/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropFilter-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_3137]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function
```

My batch size is 32 as defined in my dataset. I believe it has something to do with how I am using the tf.Datasets. Previously, I just loaded all the data into memory and the model ran just fine. However, because my dataset is much larger now, I shifted to using tf.Datasets to input the data. This required me to input the 2 images together in a single tensor as the input. It also required me to add the tf.split and squeeze methods to separate the images inside the model.

The shape of train_data is a nested structure as follows:
(batch: 32, features: [2, 128, 128, 3], labels: a scalar (the vertical movement between the two images))

```py
def load_data(image_files):
    image_file, image_file2 = bytes.decode(image_files.numpy()[0]), bytes.decode(image_files.numpy()[1])
    # Extract number of png file
    run_folder = image_file[:image_file.rfind('\\')][:-6]
    pic_number = int(image_file[image_file.rfind('\\')+1:image_file.find('.')])

    # Grab the y positions for the indicated pictures, then find their difference
    with open(run_folder+"\\yPos.txt", 'r') as yPosFile:
        for _ in range(pic_number):
            yPosFile.readline()
        oldY = float(yPosFile.readline())
        dY = float(yPosFile.readline()) - oldY

    # Load in the images from their file names, and strip the Alpha value from the RGBA values. It's always 255, so we don't need that extra data.
    image = imageio.imread(image_file)
    # Scale the RGB data down to between 0-1 so that the model has an easier time creating weights.
    return image[:, :, :-1]/255, imageio.imread(image_file2)[:, :, :-1]/255, dY


# Takes the list of output from the load_data function (which must be wrapped in tf.py_function)
# and outputs the data in the nested structure necessary for training, which the map function can process.
# Unfortunately, the py_function cannot output nested data structures, so we have to do a little wrapping here.
def load_data_wrapper(image_files):
    image, image2, dY = tf.py_function(load_data, [image_files], [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32])
    return ([image, image2], dY)


# Takes dataset like [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
# and converts it to: [[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
def prep_dataset(dtst):
    # First repeat individual elements, then print those repeated elements after each other
    dtst = dtst.interleave(lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(x).repeat(2), cycle_length=2, block_length=2)
    # Skip the first element so that numbers are paired with the next greatest in the sequence with the batch function. 
    return dtst.skip(1).batch(2, drop_remainder=True) #.take_while(lambda x: tf.squeeze(tf.greater(tf.shape(x), 1)))


def tf_load_data():
    runs = os.listdir("Data")
    image_datasets = None

    for run in runs:
        image_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("Data/"+run+"/photos/?.png", shuffle=False).apply(prep_dataset)
        image_dataset = image_dataset.map(load_data_wrapper, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
        if image_datasets == None:
            image_datasets = image_dataset
        else:
            image_datasets = image_datasets.concatenate(image_dataset)

    #print(image_datasets)

    image_datasets = image_datasets.shuffle(buffer_size=int(599*25/32)).batch(32)

    # for data in image_datasets.take(1):
    #     print(data)

    return image_datasets


def main():
    # Create model

    # Start with smaller model that processes the two images in the same way.
    single_image_input = keras.Input(shape=(128,128,3))

    image = layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3))(single_image_input)
    image = layers.LeakyReLU()(image)
    image = layers.BatchNormalization()(image)
    # Run through MaxPool2D to help the algorithm identify features in different areas of the image.
    # Has the effect of downsampling and cutting the dimensions in half.
    image = layers.MaxPool2D()(image)

    image = layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3))(image)
    image = layers.LeakyReLU()(image)
    image = layers.BatchNormalization()(image)
    image = layers.Dropout(.3)(image)

    image_model = keras.Model(single_image_input, image)
    
    # Create larger model
    image_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(2,128,128,3))

    first_image, second_image = tf.split(image_inputs, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=1)
    first_image, second_image = tf.squeeze(first_image), tf.squeeze(second_image)

    image_outputs = [image_model(first_image), image_model(second_image)]
    model = layers.Concatenate()(image_outputs)

    model = layers.Flatten()(model)

    model = layers.Dense(128)(model)
    model = layers.LeakyReLU()(model)
    model = layers.BatchNormalization()(model)
    model = layers.Dropout(.3)(model)

    # Output is change in y-position of drone
    out_layer = layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')(model)

    final_model = keras.Model(image_inputs, out_layer)
    final_model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0003, beta_1=0.7))

    image_model.summary()

    final_model.summary()


    #Preprocess data
    print("Loading and processing data...")
    train_data = tf_load_data()

    #Train model
    final_model.fit(train_data, epochs=5)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    #tf_load_data()
```

Here is my full code file and a sample of the data that I am working with in case it helps: [Data](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/files/7331695/Data.and.Code.zip)

Comment: You need to create two `Input` layers for the two images. Don't use `tf.squeeze` and `tf.split` as they aren't differentiable.

Comment: I confirm that the full model works well on the synthetic data, the problem seems to be with the dataset. Could you share the data or tell us where to find it for testing?

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I tried using two `Input` layers instead of splitting, but then the model throws an error before it finishes compiling saying that I've only supplied one input tensor. 
It seems to be interpreting my dataset as one tensor of shape `(2, 128, 128, 3)` instead of two tensors of shape `(128, 128, 3)`.

Comment: Small correction to my previous comment. It errors out when I call fit() expecting 2 inputs but receiving one. Also, I provided a link to some of my data in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a code that uses the Sequence class from Keras. The code is quite simple and it works. I understand that tf.datasets are more attractive, but you are doing complex operations.

```
class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
def __init__(self, datadir, batch_size=32, shuffle=True):
    # 'Initialization'
    self.datdir = datadir
    self.yposdir = datadir
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.shuffle = shuffle
    
    # read Y positions
    with open(os.path.join(datadir, 'yPos.txt'), 'r') as f:
        yData = [float(s) for s in f.readlines()]
    self.yData = np.array(yData)
    print(self.yData.shape)

    self.photofiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(datadir, 'photos', '*'))
    print(len(self.photofiles))
    # get image size
    image0 = np.array(imageio.imread(self.photofiles[0]))
    self.xsize, self.ysize, _ = image0.shape
    print(self.xsize)
    print(self.ysize)
    
    n_samples = len(self.photofiles)
    self.set_len = n_samples-1
    self.indexes = range(self.set_len)

    if self.shuffle == True:
        self.indexes = random.sample(range(self.set_len), k=self.set_len)
    
def __len__(self):
    return self.set_len//self.batch_size

def __getitem__(self, index):
    # Generate indexes of the batch
    indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
    
    ypos = np.zeros((self.batch_size,), dtype='float32')
    image_concat_pair_batch = np.zeros((self.batch_size, 2, self.xsize, self.ysize, 3), dtype='float32')
    
    for count, ind in enumerate(indexes):
        # get images
        curr_image = imageio.imread(self.photofiles[ind])
        next_image = imageio.imread(self.photofiles[ind+1])
        # get positions
        curr_ypos = self.yData[ind]
        new_ypos = self.yData[ind+1]
        # diff
        ypos[count] = new_ypos-curr_ypos
        # expand axis
        curr_image = np.array(curr_image)[np.newaxis, :, :, :-1]
        next_image = np.array(next_image)[np.newaxis, :, :, :-1]
        # concatenat image pairs
        image_concat = np.concatenate((curr_image, next_image), axis=0)/255.
        # store
        image_concat_pair_batch[count] = image_concat
    
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(image_concat_pair_batch, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32), tf.convert_to_tensor(ypos, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)

def on_epoch_end(self):
    if self.shuffle == True:
        self.indexes = random.sample(range(self.set_len), k=self.set_len)
```

Comment: Thank you @elbe! I did not even know Keras Sequences existed! This worked great for what I needed! I slightly modified the code you provided as my data is larger than the sample I provided, but it works now!